# XPath to select src attribute in iMacro for Firefox not working?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<div class="product-thumbnails" data-show="5">
  <div href="http://cdn.palmgren.com/images/products/9661051.jpg" 
       class="item-image" title="">
    <img width="100" height="128" 
         src="http://cdn.palmgren.com/images/thumbnails/9661051.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div href="http://cdn.palmgren.com/images/products/9661101_death_stop.jpg"
       class="item-image" title="">
    <img width="100" height="128" src="" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have written the code below to extract `src` i.e. `http://cdn.palmgren.com/images/thumbnails/9661051.jpg` but it is not working.   Please help me to correct the code.

```
TAG XPATH="//div[@class="product-thumbnails"]/div[1]/img" EXTRACT=src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath (adding a `/@src` to your original)

```
//div[@class="product-thumbnails"]/div[1]/img/@src
```

will select

```
http://cdn.palmgren.com/images/thumbnails/9661051.jpg
```

as requested.

Comment: It is not working, i am getting an error mentioned below in iMacro for firefox

"TypeError: element.style is undefined, line: 1 (Error code: -1001)"

Comment: I have figured it out

just replaced the =src with =HREF at the end and it worked.

TAG XPATH="//div[@class="product-thumbnails"]/div[1]/img" EXTRACT=HREF

Comment: I'm only answering from an XPath perspective -- not iMacro -- but note that `img` in your example has no `href` attribute.